# How about a what-if tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

Just musing -- there are a measurable number of questions which, while more or less physics-related, are a much better fit for what-if.xkcd.   Is it worth creating a "what-if" tag for these?

The discussion at [Are outlandish XKCD style What If questions welcome here?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1557) seems to suggest at least some interest in this type of question.

Comment: It sounds like you're implying that such questions are arguably off-topic here ("while more or less physics-related, are a much better fit for what-if.xkcd")  If that's the case, why would you want a tag for them?

Comment: This is a very good question to ask. I'm undecided on which answer I would support, though.

Comment: @Sean I think it's more a case of "there's a Physics.SE answer but it might be better handled in a more general sense at what-if."

Answer (score 6):

No because it would necessarily be a [meta tag](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/), which is generally discouraged.

---

Note also that the [Help Center](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) specifically states that,

> To prevent your question from being flagged and possibly removed, avoid asking subjective questions where …
>   ...
>   • you are asking an open-ended, hypothetical question: “What if ______ happened?"

so these "what-if" style questions are actually off-topic, according to current policy.